# jQuery highlight words on search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to throw together a search box that will highlight words within an element when they are typed into the box. So far, it is working for individual words but when something contains a space, its only finding the first part of it.

The code uses a plugin to do the highlighting but I think the issue is more so in the `data` that is being passed to the plugin in order to highlight it.

I believe that `data[d]` is splitting the words and its only finding the first one in the array.

My goal here is to be able to search `super cool` (in the fiddle) and have it highlight both words as it is a match.

```
$("#ruleSearch").keyup(function() {

  // Split the current value of searchInput
  var data = this.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");

  if (this.value == "") {
    $('.ruleDetailsPlaceholder').unhighlight();
    return;
  }

  for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {

      // Highlight our query within the rule
    $('.ruleDetailsPlaceholder').unhighlight();
    $('.ruleDetailsPlaceholder').highlight(data[d]);

    return true;

  }
  return false;
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g60ps0xw/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just store `this.value.toLowerCase()` in `data`, then remove the loop and have:

```
$('.ruleDetailsPlaceholder').unhighlight();
$('.ruleDetailsPlaceholder').highlight(data);
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/en08ewap/1/). Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle that will highlight both "super" and "cool".

https://jsfiddle.net/g25othfy/

Notice in your code that the:

```
   $('.ruleDetailsPlaceholder').unhighlight();
```

will be called for every element in the 'data' array. So, what is happening is that data[0] is being highlighted, then un-highlighted, then data[1] is being highlighted, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ruleSearch").keyup(function() {
    var data = this.value.toLowerCase();
    $('.ruleDetailsPlaceholder').unhighlight();
    if (data !== "") $('.ruleDetailsPlaceholder').highlight(data);
})
```

will find "super cool" but not "super stuff"