# Highlight search text in DOM results (Not the HTML code)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of data added to a DIV using innerHTML, the data includes HTML Code (`<a><div><p>` etc) and also Base64 images.

Do any one know how can I search and highlight the searched keywords?

I've seeing some examples where they added a `<span>searched keyword</span>` which this span will have a css to do the trick of the highlight, this is totally fine and a good idea except that if I search example **a**, this will replace `<a>Link</a>` with `<<span with style>a</span>>Link</<span with style>a</span>>`, not to mention what it would do to the bunch of a characters that will be in the base64 image. Anyone?

```
let text = "Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car";
let result = text.replace(/blue/gi, "red");
```

Comment: In other words I want the search to totally ignore what is inside the brackets <>...

Comment: Store the unformatted search separately from the formatted one.  When you search, search on the unformatted, apply the formatting and output the formatted (while keeping the unformatted separate)

Comment: If that's not the issue, then search on `.text()` not `.html()`.   Your example `let text=` doesn't include HTML nor where you get the value from.   If it's from the DOM then use .text()

Comment: Can someone share a jsfiddle??, Let's say I have this var = "<a>hello, guys</a> <img src="massive base64 code"> <p> Another text</p>"
How can I search only on hello, guys and Another text and most important Highlight the search??

Comment: There are some good plugins out there that have taken all of this and more into consideration.

Comment: Can you name some?, I tried Mark.JS and it doesn't do what I want, as soon as I put example a in the search, the whole thing is a mess, assuming because is adding the span etc.

Comment: Here's an SO question with a highlight()/unhighlight() function that does what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293264/jquery-highlight-words-on-search

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using mark.js and worked after all ... Thanks  all for your answers